# Remove space in bar charts in high charts for undefined values

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm creating a bar chart using high charts. Here is a sample:  http://jsfiddle.net/anishantha87/kfg5c/3/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Europe', 'Oceania','France'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            },
         },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [ 203, 200,200]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 1900',
            data: [ 408, 60,null]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 2008',
            data: [ 732, 34,null]
        }]
    });
});
```

In that I have null value for France. It displays the bar down below the France.(not vertically aligned with the Y axis name)

Any suggestions pls?

Comment: This is by design. It shows that there is no date for the other 2 series points for France.

Comment: Y axis displays just the name. What i'm expecting is to vertically aligned the bar with the y Axis.

Comment: When it created the first 3 columns, it assigned positions immediately and the chart doesn't change them depending on null values. You can try to use javascript code, find the svg tag of the column and change the `x` property from 19.5 to 37.5.

Comment: As @wergerld said - this is how Highcharts works. Calculates space for categories, then divide between series. It doesn't matter if you have data or not - space is taken for possible points.